# Not able to connect 3rd monitor via HDMI to VGA connector

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, display-settings, display-driver

I am using Windows 7 and NVdia g610 basic graphics card.

I have connected 2 monitors using VGA and DVI respectively.

Now I have connected 3rd monitor using HDMI to VGA connector. As soon as I had connected that, One of my screen went off. It means It was showing output only on 2 screen. One from HDMI to VGA connector and one from VGA.

But somehow I reverted changes.

[image]

As we can see in the picture. Third screen is detected but its disabled. Once I click on it, it shows that display is disconnected. Why I can not run 3rd screen as extended display?

Comment: 'HDMI to VGA connector's do not exist. VGA is analog only. HDMI is digital only. No connector is going to solve that. For this to work you would need an active convertor.

Comment: @Hennes , I purchased it from http://www.amazon.in/iConnect-Converter-Adapter-Desktops-Power-Free/dp/B00QCQ3IW8/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1441816886&sr=1-1&keywords=hdmi+to+vga+converter+iconnect

Comment: That looks like either bad info or (maybe good) adventising. `Cable Converter Adapter ` is either a `convertor` or an `adaptor`.  I guess they get more hits if they wire their description this way though. Product show is really a convertor though which does active conversion by interpreting one kind of signal (HDMI) and outputting that with diffferent signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sound of it, you can get display out of each monitor, and each connection, just only 2 screens at a time. That suggests you're using the correct connectors and adapters.

NVIDIA are a bit unclear about how many monitors their cards support. The geforce.co.uk site has 3 different values I've seen for the "Multi Monitor" support in their specifications - either "No", "Yes" or "4". I think "Yes" means 2, and for anything higher, they specify the number.

http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-610/specifications

I had this issue with a lower end Geforce 4xx series card. It was marked as "Yes" for multi monitor support, but only supported 2 monitors. Had to upgrade to a better/more expensive card run 3.